# jquery datatable not returning information

Tags: jquery

Everyone,

I seem to experience a weird issue with datatables in Jquery. I have a page which opens a new window on click. The new page is a datatable. If the page open using my ip address (192.168.1.12) then I get an error message stating that JSON data from the server cannot be parsed.

But it I change the ip address to localhost it works fine.

However, this behaviour does not apply to all the computers. So computers are able to connect to my server and use the IP Address and some give the same error message.

I cannot think as to why this might be happening.

Thanks
Saj

Answer (score 0):

> Two ways: 1. remove the validation plug-in, 
>   2. upgrade to the very
>   latest validation plug-in code (
>   https://github.com/bigfix/jquery-validation/commit/9aa53f9241224ba349f9fe1b2c801be0f431b63b
>   ).
>
> There are quite a few discussions on the web about this issue with
>   jQuery 1.5 and the jQuery validation plug-in (
>   http://www.google.com/#q=jquery+1.5+validate ). Basically it appears
>   that the plug-in wraps and overwrites the $.ajax stuff, thus causing
>   the problem since Ajax for an overhaul in jQuery 1.5.

Source: [DataTables forum](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4133/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed-/p1)

Comment: Interesting. It also seems to behave differently depending on the browser. On the same machine, chrome does not work but works fine in IE.